# MGCV P-Spline Smoothing Parameter

Tags: regression, spline, smoothing, mgcv

I'm fitting a P-Spline to some data using the MGCV package and the gam() function. From what I understand gam() chooses the smoothing parameter - lambda - which appears in the penalised least squares function by minimising GCV.

Does `fit$sp`return the value of lambda chosen by minimising GCV?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

The default criteria for smoothing parameter selection is GCV.

This question is more appropriate for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

That said, it seems that many are asking R modeling questions over here.